# Line spacing between paragraphs

Tags: text

For the following code, the output looks like as follows where there's no spacings between each paragraphs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[2-2]

    \lipsum[2-2]
    
    \lipsum[2-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, for the blue text in my notes, there's clearly a spacing between the 2 paragraphs:
[image]

What has gone wrong in my following code to result in that spacing?

```
\subsubsection{Vertical Spacing}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Vertical spacing is the amount of vertical space between lines.
    \item It could be spacing between two paragraphs, or two text and image, or text and a table.
    \item By default, there is no spacing between 2 paragraphs, e.g. \textbackslash lipsum[1-2] gives:\\
        \textcolor{blue}{\lipsum[1-2]}
```

Comment: somewhere in code not set you seem to  have set \parskip (or indirectly via a list \parsep) but if you show no code, it's hard to comment on where or what to change.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it is worth noting, though that the default setting for `\parskip` in LaTeX is `0pt plus1pt` which can make surprising inter-paragraph spacings appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside an itemize, the spacing between paragraphs is set by `\parsep` which is a different value than used in regular text. In `article`, the default value at the top level of a list is 4pt plus2pt minus1pt¹ if your document is set in 10pt type. Given that multiple-paragraph items in a list are not indented by default, the extra spacing helps to identify the paragraph breaks.

This amount is generally set by the document class via a private macro called `\@listi`. Here is the definition² from `size10.clo` which is the common code for the default LaTeX classes:

```
\def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
            \parsep 4pt plus2pt minus1pt
            \topsep 8pt plus2pt minus4pt
            \itemsep4pt plus2pt minus1pt}
```

You could, if you wanted, redefine this to be

```
\def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
            \parsep\parskip
            \listparindent\parindent
            \topsep 8pt plus2pt minus4pt
            \itemsep4pt plus2pt minus1pt}
```

(surrounding it with `\makeatletter`…`\makeatother` so you can access the private macro name) to have the indentation of paragraphs and spacing between them be the same as in the main document.

---

1. Certain dimensions in LaTeX, called glue in LaTeX parlance (or skips in TeX primitive-speak) can stretch or shrink. When you see a `plus` or `minus` in that context, it's indicating the amount the glue can stretch or shrink.
2. This is not exactly the code you'd see in the file. I changed some abbreviations that are used because when LaTeX was originally written, the capacity of TeX was greatly limited and a lot of care was taken to reduce memory usage.